# Representing pairs of values that lead to a constant

Tags: equation-solving, graphics, mathematical-optimization

I have the following expression:

$Q=\frac{\sqrt{rc}}{1+r(1+K)}$

Q and K are constant values. Basically I want to plot a graph that shows me all the combinations of r and c that verify the equation. Moreover I want to find the optimal pair (r,c) (basically the best compromise that minimizes both values) that allows to fulfill the condition. Any guess on how to do it in Mathematica?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `q=7;k=4;FindInstance[q==Sqrt[r c]/(1+r(1+k)),{r,c},Integers,20]` for your Q and K values and see how many integer solutions it finds, For the handful I tried it only seemed to find one or two solutions and could not prove there were no more. If you are not limiting this to integer values, or if q or k are not integers, then there might be other solutions.

Comment: Hello Bill! Yes they don't need to be integers, all these values (Q,k,r and c) are positive reals.

Answer (score 3):

I plead ignorance of typical values K, Q. However, this may be  helpful.

Defining Q as f:

```
  f[r_, c_, k_] := Sqrt[r c]/(1 + r (1 + k))
```

Solving for (r,c) given K, Q (as c can be expressed as function of r):

```
 opt[a_, b_] := Quiet[Module[{w, ans, y},
       w = c /. Solve[f[r, c, a] == b, {r, c}][[1]];
       ans = r /. Solve[D[w, r] == 0 && r > 0, r][[1]];
       {ans, w} /. r -> ans
       ]]
```

Visualizing:

```
cp[k_, q_] := Module[{pts = opt[k, q]},
  ContourPlot[f[r, c, k] == q, {r, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"Q=", q, ", K=", k}], 
   Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts], Text[pts, pts, {-1, 1}]}]]
```

Some examples:

```
Partition[
  Flatten[Table[cp[j, k], {j, 1, 3, 0.5}, {k, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}]], 
  5] // Grid
```

Note (r,c) plane. Critical r value 1/(1+k)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For fixed values of `k` and `q`, you can plot `{r,c}` pairs satisfying the constraint using [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html).

```
ClearAll[f]
f[r_, c_, k_, q_] := q - Sqrt[r c]/(1 + r + r k)

options = {ImageSize -> 500, PlotPoints -> 60, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}};

ContourPlot[{f[r, c, 7/10, 3/5] == 0,
  f[r, c, 1/2, 2/3], 
  f[r, c, 9/10, 2/5], 
  f[r, c, 2/5, 3/5]}, 
 {r, 0, 3}, {c, 0, 10}, 
 Evaluate @ options, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Right, Top}, Style[#, 18] &]]
```

[image]

You can use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to interactively change the values of `k` and `q`.

First a few functions to help with streamlining `Manipulate` inputs:

```
ClearAll[bSF, objectiveFunctionContours, displayFunction, plots]

bSF[k_, q_] := First @ Cases[Normal @ 
    ContourPlot[f[r, c, k, q] == 0, {r, 0, 3}, {c, 0, 10}], 
    Line[x_] :> BSplineFunction[x], All];

objectiveFunctionContours[w_] := 
 ParametricPlot[# Normalize[w, Total] {t, 1 - t} & /@ Range[20], {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thickness[Small]]]

displayFunction[w_] := 
 Module[{pt = First @ Cases[Normal @ #, Point[x_] :> x, All]}, 
   Show[#, PlotLabel -> 
     Style[Row[{w . (HoldForm /@ {r, c}), 
        "  is minimized at {r, c} = ", NumberForm[pt, {∞, 3}], 
        "\n with value = ", NumberForm[w . pt, {∞, 4}]}], 16], 
    Epilog -> {Red, InfiniteLine[{pt, {0, (1/w) . pt}}]}]] &

plots[k_, q_, rcweights_ : {1, 1}] :=
 Module[{bsF = bSF[k, q],
   df = displayFunction[rcweights], 
   ofcontours = objectiveFunctionContours[rcweights]}, 
  Show[ParametricPlot[bsF[t], {t, 0, 1},
    MeshFunctions -> {(1/rcweights) . bsF'[#3] &},
    Evaluate @ options,
    DisplayFunction -> df], ofcontours]]
```

*Problem 1*: Given `k`, `q` and `rw` (relative weight of  `r` in the objective function `w rw + c`)  find `{r,c}` that minimizes `r rw + c` subject to the constraints `f[r,c,k,q] == 0 && r >= 0 && c >= 0`

The following `Manipulate` allows interactive exploration of *Problem 1* showing the constraint set (where `f[r,c,k,q]==0`), objective function contours (orange lines), and the point (red dot) that solves the constrained minimization problem.

```
Manipulate[plots[k, q, {wr, 1}],
 {{k, .7}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", LabelStyle -> 14},
 {{q, .6}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", LabelStyle -> 14},
 {{wr, 1, "relative weight of r"}, 0, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  LabelStyle -> 14}]
```

[image]

Comment: Re _"the optimal pair"_, you need to specify a positive lower bound for the variables to avoid the trivial solution `r==c==k==q==0`.

Comment: Really cool, such minimizations really 'rock'!